# Is there a way to pass a function reference between activities?

Tags: android, kotlin

is there a way of bundling function references in Kotlin and Android so that the functions can be called from other fragments? 
For instance, my fragment factory method looks like this:

```
    fun newInstance(tryAgainFunction: () -> Unit): TimeOutHandlerFragment {
        val fragment = TimeOutHandlerFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()

        return fragment
    }
```

I want to be able to save my tryAgainFunction in the bundle for further retrieval.

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**

In the end, the most suitable solution was using hotkey's answer and then in onViewCreated I initializing a listener with the passed function. The complete code is as follows:

```
companion object {
    val CALLBACK_FUNCTION: String = "CALLBACK_FUNCTION"

    fun newInstance(tryAgainFunction: () -> Unit): TimeOutHandlerFragment {
        val fragment = TimeOutHandlerFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putSerializable(CALLBACK_FUNCTION, tryAgainFunction as Serializable)
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    try {
        val callback: () -> Unit = arguments.getSerializable(CALLBACK_FUNCTION) as () -> Unit
        btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener { callback.invoke() }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        // callback has a wrong format
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `tryAgainFunction` is `Serializable`, then [you can put it into the `bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable) using `bundle.putSerializable("try_again_function", tryAgainFunction);`.

It will actually be `Serializable` if it is a function reference (`SomeClass::someFunction`) or a lambda. But it might not be, if it is some custom implementation of the functional interface `() -> Unit`, so you should check that and handle the cases when it's not.

Comment: I am passing this lamda: () -> LiveData<Resource<List<T>> to my activity but it is throwing NotSerializableException. Can you please expand on how we can handle this case?

Comment: @RiteshChandnani You can't do anything in that case. If your lambda has reference to a non-serializable object then it will crash. `LiveData` is not serializable so it will crash as expected. What you can do is to pass `List<T>` as serializable in the intent and make your `T` implement `Serializable`

Answer (score 12):

2022 Update:

1. My original approach has a drawback, in my demo if I press the home button to put the app into the background, it will crash with  `NotSerializableException`.
2. Actually there is another API just for listening changes from one `Fragment` in the other, that is `FragmentResultListener`, offical tutorial is here: https://youtu.be/oP-zXjkT0C0?t=468.
3. If `FragmentResultListener` cannot meet your need, `Shared ViewModel` is the final solution in there: https://youtu.be/THt9QISnIMQ.

---

**1. You need to add `id 'kotlin-parcelize'` to your build.gradle (app), like this:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'    //here
}
```

**2. Create a Class to wrap your Lambda function:**

```
@Parcelize
class Listener(val clickAction: () -> Unit) : Parcelable {
    fun onClick() = clickAction()
}
```

**3. Pass your Lambda:**

```
val bundle = Bundle().apply {
    putParcelable("listener", Listener(clickAction))
}

private val clickAction: () -> Unit = {    
    //do your stuff
}
```

**4. Retrieve it:**

```
arguments?.getParcelable<Listener>("listener")?.onClick()
```

---

**Demo** (all `Fragment`s): https://youtu.be/0OnaW4ZCnbk

Comment: Like all the other solutions I get a NotSerializableException when the fragments activity goes to the backstack.

Comment: Anyone found a solution for NotSerializableException when activities go to the back stack?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe too late but:

Have you tried to put the `val callback` inside the companion object?
Solution may be something like:

```
companion object {
    private lateinit var callback 

    fun newInstance(tryAgainFunction: () -> Unit): TimeOutHandlerFragment {
        val fragment = TimeOutHandlerFragment()
        this.callback = tryAgainFunction
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener { callback.invoke() }
}
```

Comment: But remember, if you do so, the variable is going to be "static" and therefore shared between all object of the same class. In your case is fine because rarely you are going to have more than one instance of the same activity.

Comment: can you please share how tryAgainFunction will be passed to the newInstance function

Comment: MyClass.newInstance() { 
    tryAgainFunction() }

Comment: Instead of a "static" var, why can't we use the function as a constructor parameter? It works fine until I found that in some devices (Xiaomi) I was getting `could not find Fragment constructor` then I switched to hotkey's solution.

Comment: But now I have a problem, my callbacks fail to `Serialize` when Fragment's Activity goes to background with `NotSerializableException`. Example of a callback: `(String?, List<Int>?) -> (Unit)`and `(Boolean) -> (Unit)`

Answer (score 3):

No, as others say, there is no way of passing a function literal to `Bundle`.

But since `enum` implements `Serializable`, you can pass enum variables that can hold some methods.
Try below codes;

```
enum class SampleEnum(val f: () -> Unit) {
    Sample0({
        Log.d("enum Test", "sample 0")
    }),
    Sample1({
        Log.d("enum Test", "sample 1")
    }),
}
```

in your from-activity (or fragment);

```
bundle.putSerializable("sample_enum",SampleEnum.Sample0)
```

in your to-activity (or fragment);

```
 // invoke your fuction
(bundle.getSerializable("sample_enum") as SampleEnum).f()
```

Comment: An interesting solution, although I have to create a new enum instance every time I want to pass a function like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, there is a simple solution to this that I've been using in my projects. The idea is to wrap any reference types/objects in a warper class that is `Parcalabe` and `Serializable` without actually implementing marshaling of the underlying reference type. Here is the wrapper class and how to use it without causing any potential memory leak:

```
@Parcelize @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class TrackedReference<ReferenceType: Any> private constructor(
    private var uniqueID: Int = -1
) : Serializable, Parcelable {

    constructor(reference: ReferenceType) : this() {
        uniqueID = System.identityHashCode(this)
        referenceMap.set(uniqueID, reference)
    }

    val get: ReferenceType?
        get() = referenceMap.get(uniqueID) as? ReferenceType

    fun removeStrongReference() {
        get?.let { referenceMap.set(uniqueID, WeakReference(it)) }
    }

    companion object {
        var referenceMap = hashMapOf<Int, Any>()
            private set
    }

}
```

Any object can be wrapped in a `TrackedReference` object and passed as serializable or parcelable:

```
class ClassA {
    fun doSomething { }
}

// Add instance of ClassA to an intent
val objectA = ClassA()
intent.putExtra("key", TrackedReference(objectA))
```

You can also pass a `weak` or `soft` reference depending on the use case.

**Use case 1:**

The object (in this case `objectA`) is not guaranteed to be in memory by the time the receiver activity needs to use it (e.g. might be garbage collected).

In this case, the object is kept in memory until you explicitly remove the strong reference.
Pass in an `Intent` or `Bundle` inside this wrapper and accesse in a straightforward manner, e.g. (psuedocode)

```
class ClassA {
    fun doSomething { }
}

// Add instance of ClassA to an intent
val objectA = ClassA()
intent.putExtra("key", TrackedReference(objectA))

// Retrieve in another activity
val trackedObjectA = intent.getSerializable("key") as TrackedReference<ClassA>
trackedObjectA.get?.doSomething()

// Important:- to prevent potential memory leak,
// remove *strong* reference of a tracked object when it's no longer needed.
trackedObjectA.removeStrongReference()
```

**Use case 2:**

The object is guaranteed to be in memory when needed, e.g. an activity that is housing a fragment is guaranteed to remain in memory for the lifecycle of the fragment.

Or, we do not care if the object is garbage collected, and we do not want to be the reason for its existence. In this case, pass a `weak` or `soft` reference when initializing a `TrackedReference` instance:

```
// Removing the strong reference is not needed if a week reference is tracked, e.g. 
val trackedObject = TrackedReference(WeakReference(objectA)) 
trackedObject.get?.doSomething()
```

Its best to understand why `Intent` requires `Parcelable` or `Serializable` and what's the best way to use this workaround in a given scenario.

It's certainly not ideal to serialize objects to allow *delegation* or *callback* communication between activities.

Here is the *[documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Types)* on `Intent` but simply put, an `Intent` is passed to the *Android System* which then looks-up what to do with it and in this case starts the next Activity (which can be another app as far as the *Android System* receiving the intent is concerned). Therefore, the system needs to make sure that everything inside an intent can be reconstructed from parcels.

**Rant:**

IMO, `Intent` as a higher level abstraction for IPC (Inter Process Communication) maybe convenient and efficient internally but at the cost of these limitations.
It's maybe comparing Apples to oranges but in iOS, *ViewControllers* (similar to *Activities*) are like any class and can be passed any `Type` (value or reference) as an argument. The developer is then responsible to avoid potential reference-cycles that might prevent ARC (memory management) to free unused references.

Comment: This will either throw a NotSerializableException or RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal, when you leave the app or enter a background

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create interface and extend serializable

```
interface ItemClickListener : Serializable {
    fun onItemClick(item: ItemModel)
}
```

2 - Pass to instance of fragment, dialogFragment or BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
companion object {

    const val KEY = "itemClickListener"

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(itemClickListener: ItemClickListener) =
        ItemFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {                  
                putSerializable(KEY, itemClickListener)
            }
        }
}
```

3  - in fragment, dialogFragment or BottomSheetDialogFragment, `onCreate`

```
//declare nullable variable
private var itemClickListener: ItemClickListener? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    arguments?.let {      
        itemClickListener = it.getSerializable(KEY, ItemClickListener::class.java)
    }
}
```

By doing this, you will be safe if device change `dark mode or light mode`, `configuration change`, `screen rotation`.

Answer (score -1):

If it is not possible to put a function literal into a `Bundle`, however, you can pass the function to the `Fragment` through a setter like function in the `Fragment`.

```
fun setTryAgainFunction(tryAgainFunction: () -> Unit) {

}
```

Comment: This will work only until the fragment gets recreated if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. We can either set it again after recreation, or instead of setter, we can use getter.

Comment: But Hotkey's solution is better.