# Passing function from one activity to another via Broadcasts

Tags: android, android-studio, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to pass a function from one activity to another using Broadcasts. Like we can pass Strings and int by `putExtra`, Is there a way I can pass a whole function? I know there are other ways to do this, but I need to do this with the help of broadcasts. Any help?

Ex:

```
void myFunc(){ /* foo */ }
```

Can I use `myFunc` in some other activity via broadcast? I don't mind declaring the function again in the new activity as long as I get data from broadcast.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617564/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-function-reference-between-activities it is basically what you are asking for (works the same in Kotlin and Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can pass a whole function?

No, sorry.

> Can I use myFunc in some other activity via broadcast?

No, sorry.

Alternatives:

- Use one activity rather than two
- Have both activities work with some other object that is outside each of those activities (e.g., a singleton serving as a repository)

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Can I not do it with a serializable function?
Or Somehow pass a String of my function ("void myFunc(){ /* foo */ }") and then somehow use this string to create the same function in the new activity?

Comment: @TejasSoni: "Can I not do it with a serializable function?" -- there is no such thing as a "serializable function" in Java or JVM-based languages. "Or Somehow pass a String of my function ("void myFunc(){ /* foo */ }") and then somehow use this string to create the same function in the new activity? " -- no, because Java is not an interpreted language. It is a compiled language, with the compiler being on your development machine.