# It is safe to send a function as a Serializable param to a new activity/fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

Recently I found this 
[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617564/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-function-reference-between-activities) which describes how we can pass an external function to a fragment as a Serializable Param via Bundle (similar approach can be applied to send a function to a new activity)

But my question is how safe is this approach?
This can be a source of memory leaks?
Anyone used this approach in practice?

Comment: TL;DR Don't do it, 1. Not safe 2. Yes, memory leaks 3. No, use MVC, MVP or MVVM and you won't need it