# Parcelable and serializable in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Correct me if I am wrong but in kotlin the place where we mostly need to use parcelable or serializable is when we send objects in new activity when creating it or in new fragment via bundle also during its creation.

Why do we actually need to serialize objects in these situtaions? We can send objects through our classes all the time normally but in these cases we have to serialize them into byte stream to send them.
Why is that so?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50268350/4729721)

Comment: ok thanks for answer

Comment: @a_local_nobody one more thing. they blocked my account for asking more questions :(
Could you undo the question duplicate so I realive my account?

Comment: That's not how the site works. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: @Zoe so practically I can do nothing to fix this :(

Comment: Oh, you can. You can also chose not to (which appears to be the road you're going down, at least with that attitude)

Comment: Yes I will have to change my questions and let people upvote it. But I believe there is low chance of people coming to my old questions and upvoting it in short period of time. Maybe even never

Comment: Hey look at this, somebody upvoted my questions and I am free again :D
Did you do that?

Comment: I looked at your old questions and upvoted some good ones. Whatever this algorithm is doing seems like it was absurdly harsh on you because you have many good questions and only two closed ones.

Comment: Wooow thanks man you're the best <3
I send peace and love from Croatia!!!